# Selenium Webdriver Tab focus shifted but it is not visible

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am working on a public site:  preview.harriscountyfws.org

I want to capture the original tab's reference so I can get back to it, because
when I click a link on the main page, a new tab is opened.

How do I switch back to the first tab?
It seems that the execution of the code is still working off of the original tab, but I can't see it.  I want to be able to see it while the test is going on.

Here is my code:

```
WebDriver driver;
WebElement we;

driver.get("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href=\"/Alerts\"]"));
if (we != null) we.click(); else System.out.println("Failed Link Click");
// try {Thread.sleep(2000);} catch  (InterruptedException ie) {system.out.println("err"");

driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.PAGE_UP);
```

It should shift the focus to original tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
```

Comment: this is helpful in switching execution to a different window.  it is a valuable tip.  switching execution doesn't always change what is visible on the screen though....

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below, worked for me.

```
    public class Win { 

    @Test
    public void f() {
    WebDriver driver;
    WebElement we;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/dell/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

  we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href=\"/Alerts\"]"));
  if (we != null) we.click(); else System.out.println("Failed Link Click");

  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  By docLibrary = By.xpath(".//*[@id='NavMenu']/ul/li[4]/div/a");
  driver.findElement(docLibrary).click();
  }
 }
```